# Homomorphism $f:M \to M$ such that $\mathrm{im}(f) = L$ and $f \circ f = f$ where $L \le M$ and $M$ abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $M$ be an abelian group. For any subgroup $L$ of $M$, can you find a homomorphism $f:M \to M$ such that $\mathrm{im}(f) = L$ and $f \circ f = f$?

This was an attempt to find an idempotent between $R$-module $M$, where $R$ is a division ring such that the image of the idempotent is the submodule $L$ of $M$. So I started with an attempt to find such homomorphism in the level of abelian groups and then see if that map preserves scalar multiplication.

Comment: Of course not! If there is such an endomorphism then $L$ is a direct summand of $M$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, take $M=\mathbb Z$, $L=2\mathbb Z$.